# problems with classic asp if statment and reading form values

Tags: forms, if-statement, asp-classic

I have been having trouble with a bit of classic asp code

pretty much what I want to do is when a hidden field has a value of 1 a message is displayed

here is the code i have:

```
<% if (CStr(Request.form("HiddenLog")) = CStr("1")) then %>
        <br /> <p style="color:Red;">Message here</p>
        <%end if %>

        <input type="hidden" id="HiddenLog" value="1" />
```

The result is nothing appears on screen however if I add an else to the if statment like so

```
   <% if (CStr(Request.form("HiddenLog")) = CStr("1")) then %>
            <br /> <p style="color:Red;">Message here</p>
    <%else%>
            <br /> <p style="color:Red;">Message here</p>

            <%end if %>
```

The message always appears (of course this was to prove that the if statment is working and that the problem most likly is with getting the form values), can someone please tell me what it is I have done wrong

Thanks

*Edit* A couple of people have asked about my form so I will post that here as well

```
<form  id="form1" method="post">
```

all the controls are contained inside this form

Comment: Are you looking for form data or could it be the `QueryString`?

Comment: Its form data from the HiddenLog input that I am looking for

Comment: Just looking at your code there, both the `if` and `else` statements have identical content.  Also, try writing your field to the page using `<%= Request.Form("HiddenLog") %>`.  To further this; if the second piece of code is returning a value then the value returned by your logical comparison is obviously false.

Comment: is your form using a post method?

Comment: yes it is using post but the form does not have an action, I am used to using asp.net and not classic so I don't know if I need one or not

Comment: @ Westie, the if statment is returning false, thats my problem I want to know why it is returning false when the value of HiddenLog is infact 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to give the input field a name attribute. you only have an id attribute this is not posted so just use

```
<input type="hidden" id="HiddenLog" name="HiddenLog" value="1" />
```

Comment: still returning false when I added the name attribute

Comment: i really hope you are aware that Request.form("HiddenLog") is only populated after a submit?

Comment: wait, you mean there is no way to get this to populate on form load? not that it’s an issue on this case but good to know for future reference, although I tend to avoid classic asp like the black death of the obvious reason I don't really know anything about it haha Thanks for the tip